# How to debug incompatibility between .NET RIA Servces (July Preview) and Silverlight MVVM toolkit?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-templates

I have discovered that when I install .NET RIA Services (July preview) it breaks all of my projects that were created with Michael Sync's [Silverlight MVVM toolkit](http://michaelsync.net/2009/06/14/an-early-look-at-silverlight-model-view-viewmodel-toolkit-1).

This MVVM toolkit includes a Visual Studio project template which is now failing to build.  Here is the message I get:

```
The project file "..\SilverlightModelViewApplication.Web\SilverlightModelViewApplication.Web.csproj" was not found.
```

I don't find the string "SilverlightModelViewApplication" anywhere in the solution.  I get the same message if I create an empty new project using the template. If I uninstall .NET RIA Services with Programs & Features, my MVVM projects build successfully;  when I reinstall .NET RIA Services my projects fail to build again.

How can I debug this?  I posted a comment on the MVVM toolkit site but there has been no response.  Thanks!

+tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered on the [MS Silverlight forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/135612/303062.aspx#303062) by MS engineer Brett Samblanet.

Short-term fix: Turn off the RIA Service link to "SilverlightModelViewApplication.Web.csproj" in the .web project properties.

Long-term fix: Change the MVVM template .csproj file entry for `<LinkedServerProject>` to an empty entry.